# overview/history of resident memory usage

Tags: linux, memory-management

I have a fairly complicated program (Python with SWIG'ed C++ code, long running server) that shows a constantly growing resident memory usage.  I've been digging with the usual tools for the leak (valgrind, Pythons gc module, etc.) but to no avail so far.  I'm a bit afraid that the actual problem is memory fragmentation within Python and/or libc managed memory.

Anyway, my question is more specific right now:  Is there a tool to visualize resident memory usage and ideally show how it develops over time?  I think the raw data is in /proc/$PID/smaps but I was hoping there's some tool that shows me a nice graph of the amounts used by mmap'ed files vs. anonymous mmap'ed memory vs. heap over time so that it's easier to see (literally) what's changing.  I couldn't find anything though.

Does anybody know of a tool that graphs the memory map (type of memory and amount) **of a specific process** over space and time in an intuitive way?

---

**Update:**  I found the "pmap" tool but the version on my system doesn't seem to handle RSS and provides no option to merge sizes for all mapped files resp. mapped "anon" areas.  I ended up hacking a little script that parses /proc/$PID/smaps every two minutes while the original program runs and prints lines like this:

```
12:00:28 {'_TOTAL': 729.20703125, 'file': 53.609375, 'heap': 22.08984375,
          'anon': 653.5, 'stack': 0.0078125}
...
15:42:47 {'_TOTAL': 940.16015625, 'file': 53.484375, 'heap': 22.2109375,
          'anon': 864.45703125, 'stack': 0.0078125}
```

No nice graph but after a few hours of runtime I think it's a safe bet now that I have to have a closer look at the 'anon' memory segments :-)

---

**Update:** The latest release of valgrind made its memory profiler ("massif") support page level profiling by using `--pages-as-heap=yes`.  Yay!  Running my program for a few hours through massif and then feeding the resulting file into [Massif Visualizer](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdereview/massif-visualizer) resulted in a nice graph of memory consumption per page type over time, including stack traces to see where all the mmap calls were coming from.  \o/

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the created objects reference count will help you to understand where the memory is consummed by your application.

I have found this code maybe it'll help you.

http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 0):

I test with **vmstat** but its has no GUI etc, its all raw data:

```
[~]> vmstat -S K 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
1  0    172 663244 410016 187756    0    0     6    12   14    4  0  0 99  0
0  0    172 663228 410016 187756    0    0     0    68   20   66  0  0 100  0
0  0    172 663228 410016 187756    0    0     0     0   12   54  0  0 100  0
0  0    172 663228 410016 187756    0    0     0     0   20   54  0  0 100  0
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rare, but you may check for *file (or socket) leak*, I mean when the program opens files and never closes them. In my desktop configuration there were no sign of a socket leak until it ran over 1000+. Of course, they were opened cca. 1/sec, so it came up after some days. It's evil!